# EmberJS: Populate common views from server

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-app-kit

I'm beginner using EmberJS and I'm trying to play around with it.
I'm working with Ember AppKit.

I have a page, `localhost:8000/#/home`.
In my global application.hbs, I have multiple views: header, navigation, footer, and an {{outlet}} in the middle to load the current page.

**application.hbs:**

```
{{render 'header'}}
{{render 'navigation'}}
{{outlet}}
{{render 'footer'}}
```

I found the way to call the server to populate my current page `home.hbs` with the model, route and adapter.

**routes/home.js:**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('home');
    }
});
```

**adapters/home.js:**

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8000/api/home'
});
```

**models/home.js**

```
var attr = DS.attr,

export default DS.Model.extend({
   //My model
});
```

(The above is just an example)

But now I'm looking for a way to populate the content of my common views from the server as well. They are not pages, so they don't need a route. I don't want to access `localhost:8000/#/header`

Although my content is available on the API with `localhost:8000/api/content/header` 
Do you have any idea of the approach I should follow to do something like that?
I was thinking to make a call directly inside the controller using $.getJSON but I'm not sure that's the best way to do...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to load the content into the header controller etc. in the home route's `setupController` hook. I suppose you could also load the content in the `HeaderController#init` hook.

Comment: Using something like $.getJSON then?